# Using M to check if a value exists in another table (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables,

```
Table 1
Column1
Alex
Barry
Chris

Column1
Name
Miranda
Fanta
Barry
```

I want to remove any rows from Table 1 that is present in Table 2 in the query editor

To do this, I need to create a column called as IsPresent in Table1.

```
Column1  IsPresent
Alex       No
Barry      Yes
Chris      No
```

How can I create this IsPresent column using M? Is it even possible, if not why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write a custom column for this

```
if List.Contains(Column1[Name], [Column1]) then "Yes" else "No"
```

However, if your goal is just "to remove any rows from Table 1 that is present in Table 2" then you can do a [left anti join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-left-anti) instead of defining a custom column and filtering.